# How to solve the issue of a stackview bug inside Interface Builder Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a really strange bug found in Xcode's Interface Builder.

When I try to add an `UILabel` and `UITextview` inside a `stackView` using the Interface Builder, the stack view will be stretch with a width of infinite. For my `UITextView` I disabled the scroll and edit functions.

Before:

[image]

This is after I combine both elements inside a `StackView`:

[image]

When I use two UILabels and add those inside a `StackView` it's working correctly.

Comment: What constraints have you set on the stackview?  When you embed objects in a stack view most of their existing constraints will be removed.  The stack view will then use their intrinsic size to determine its size; the `UITextView` is intrinsically very long as it will try to fit all of the text on one line.  If you constrain the stack view to the edges of the superview then it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding trailing and leading constraint of the stack view itself, to the superview or to close items with well defined constraints, should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to add minimum 3 (most of the cases 4) constraints to your views in order to use autolayout.

example code:

```
    [label.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [label.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [label.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [label.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
```